# Probability understanding problems

Tags: probability

Number of students in the class who take the math test is 600.

number of students with distinction score = 90 students .

Given that a student who has obtained a distinction in The math test will be nominated for mathOlympiad .
2 students are chosen from the 600 students randomly .

What is the probability that AT MOST ONE 
student in nominated for mathOlympiad.

[image]

I have drawn the possibility tree diagram above .

I don't quite understand by "at most" 
My thoughts are that at most means that it must be one student with distinction picked and the second one picked without distinction and the other way round . 
And both students with distinction are picked is not counted .

But the probability calculated is wrong. Can I get help.. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

At most 1 means exactly 1 or 0.

$\dfrac{90}{600}\dfrac{510}{599} + \dfrac{510}{600}\dfrac{90}{599}+\dfrac{510}{600}\dfrac{509}{599}$

In this case, it also means not 2.

$1 - \dfrac{90}{600}\dfrac{89}{599}$

I will leave it to you to verify that those are equivalent.